# necesito ayudar para formular un algoritmo de numeros primos

Tags: c++, algoritmos

Como es el algoritmo que tengo que escribir para de toda una lista de numeros guardar el **primer n° primo** ingresado?

Comment: El texto se puede entender, pero realmente, ¿no podrías revisarlo un poco el intentar preguntar bien y detalladamente? Además, ¿qué investigaste? ¿qué intentaste?

Answer (score 1):

tienes varias opciones, la primera que se me ocurre es recorrer la lista e ir probando si el cada numero es primo.
Para ver si el numero es primo debes comprobar que el modulo de siempre distinto de 0 hasta la mitad de ese numero, algo asi:

```
bool esPrimo = false;
for(int i = 0; i <= numero/2 || !esPrimo; ++i) 
     if(numero % i == 0)
          esPrimo = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Uno de los más rápidos... usa el teorema de abajo.

## Teorema:

Para todo número primo p > 3, se tiene que p=6k+1 ó p=6k-1

### Demostración:

Todos los entero pueden expresarse exactamente de un de las 6 posibles formas:
6k, 6k+1, 6k+2, 6k+3, 6k-2, ó 6k-1
6k es divisible por 6, por lo que no es primo
6k+2 es par, por lo que no es primo
6k+3=3(2k+1) es divisible por 3, por lo que no es primo
6k-2 es par por lo que no es primo
Por tanto, los números primos tienen que expresarse de la forma 6k+1 ó 6k-1.
Note que no todos los números de esa forma son necesariamente primos.

#### Algoritmo para determinar si un número es primo

En muchas aplicaciones es necesario conocer si un número n es o no primo. Cuando n es muy grande, los algoritmos conocidos son muy ineficientes. Veamos el siguente que es bastante rápido para n no muy grandes.

Determinaremos si un número n es primo, si algún divisor no trivial de n es encontrado, puede asegurarse de que n es compuesto, si ningún divisor es encontrado entonces concluimos que n es primo. El algoritmo está basado entonces en una búsqueda exaustiva de un divisor de n. A continuación un pseudocódigo del algoritmo.

```
PRIME (x) // x > 3

if x mod 6 <> 1 and x mod 6 <> 5
    then return FALSE
r = SQRT(x)
i = 1
while 6*i-1 <= r do
    if x mod (6*i-1) = 0
        then return FALSE
    if x mod (6*i+1) = 0
        then return FALSE
    i = i + 1
    return TRUE
```

## La criba de Erastótenes

Este un algoritmo conocido desde la antigüedad, para determinar todos los números primos desde 2 hasta un cierto valor n.

El algoritmo está basado en "marcar" todos los números que son múltiplos de algún otro menor. Al final, los números que "hayan sobrevivido a tal marcado" por supuesto, son primos.

### CRIBA_DE_ERASTOTENES (max)

```
for i = 2 to max do
    marked[i] = FALSE
for i = 2 to max do
    if marked[i] = FALSE
        then k = 2*i
while k <= max do
    marked[k] = TRUE
    k = k + i
return marked
```